# Microsoft Word Multi-Level List with Jagged Entries

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

Here's what I currently have:

[image: Multi-Level List]

It's a mult-level list where Heading 1 is Level 1, Heading 2 is Level 2, and Body Text is Level 3. The numbering for Level 1 and Level 2 reflect the outline of the document. The numbering for Level 3 is only for referencing the specific items. Every time the style changes, I want the numbering for Level 3 to restart. And that is what I get. That's the only reason I have it defined as part of the multi-level list is so that I could tell it to restart the numbering when Level 2 changes.

This works perfectly when the Level 3 items (Body Text) appear inside a Level 2 item (Heading 2).

The problem is that if I put a Level 3 item directly inside a Level 1 item, it changes the Level 2 numbering for the next section as follows:

[image: First Instance of Heading 2 is numbered wrong]

The number for the first instance of Heading 2 changed from 1.1 to 1.2 and the number for the second instance remained unchanged.

What I want to do is be able to place Body Text directly inside any Heading 1 or Heading 2 entry and leave the Heading 1 and Heading 2 numbers unaffected. I also need the numbering of the Body Text to restart as it is.

I have tried everything I can imagine, I am hoping there is one more and that it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MS Word are you using? Have you looked at outline view?

Comment: Office 360 version. This is actually been an issue for me going way back. And yes, I looked at Outline view and it is the same -- the numbering is not correct. It even doesn't look logically correct. It just looks wrong as if it is a bug.

Comment: Have you looked at [This article on MS Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/number-your-headings-ce24e028-4cb4-4d4a-bf25-fb2c61fc6585)? You need to apply list numbering to your heading styles, and then ensure that your body text, even if it's body text to a level 1 heading, is specifically demoted in outline view to body text. If the paragraphs of body text need to be numbered, then you need to format them as lists separately from the headings.

Comment: That article only tells you how to use the built-in multi-level lists. If you have an example of the result of what you are talking about that might help. But one more thing I need to say is that it is not an option to do any formatting other than setting styles. No manual demoting or telling Word to restart numbering. The scenario is that I am taking a document that has the multi-level list and style and outputting text and style instructions via my application using openxml.

Comment: If you update the document styles to include the multilevel list numbering as part of the heading styles, and edit your document in outline view, specifically telling outline view that body text is body text (not a lower-level heading - that's what I mean by "demote to body text"), you will get the behavior that you are describing as desirable. If you further need the body text paragraphs numbered, then you should subsequently apply the numbered list format to those paragraphs, but NOT as part of a multilevel list.

Comment: Working in Outline View for this makes the levels and the structure of your document much clearer, without adversely affecting the print layout of the document.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. The problem with applying the numbered list format to the body text paragraphs is that the numbering won't restart. That is why I had them in the multilevel list -- it has a feature for restarting the numbers. That much works fine. It is the headings that don't work right, but only when body text is included between them as opposed to always appearing inside the lowest level. I'm not sure how clear I am on this but I'm trying.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong; I use this all the time, and never have a problem. Each block of body text paragraphs is a separate list, or should be, and is numbered independently of its parent.

Comment: If you could send me a sample that would be great!